# Delete/block user from Gmail chat

Tags: gmail, google-talk

How do I block a user from chatting with me? FYI, this person is already in my chat list.

Answer (score 6):

1. Hover the mouse over the name in the chat list
2. Click **More** or **Video & more** on the popup box
3. Click **Block**

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Gmail account.

- enable your chat list.
- Click on the person you want to chat.
- Now you will see the chat window at the right hand corner, in that click actions and select Block

Now the user will be blocked